# PHP/IIS - Sessions_save_path - Session Data created but an error occurs and installation can not be done

Tags: php, iis, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I am trying to build a mediawiki and I have installed IIS and PHP manually to do that.
I did all configuration and after that I wanted to begin with the Installation of mediawiki, but then the following error occur:

[image]

So I checked my php.ini and set the Session.save_path to C:\inetpub\temp\phpsessions.
There the data gets saved (see Screenshot), but the error still occurs.

[image]

Does anybody know this error and can help me, or has an idea to fix this error?

Comment: I do not know whose file is this, if it is managed by the user that runs the site in IIS (AppPoolIdentity perhaps?) then this user needs permissions on that folder. If on the other hand this is a file by the user that access the site, this user (or equivalent .. like Machine\Users) needs permissions on the folder .. maybe double check on permissions.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki uses it's own session storage (in DB or memcached/redis...), but on the installer it has to use the normal php session handler... In a load balanced setup, for this scenario, you must ensure each client is assigned to the same server, otherwise a session starting on server A, if the load balancer switches to server B, this session is not recognised and you'll end with a session data lost error.

Comment: this answer was taken from here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Tx5qcftarq8go9k5

Comment: @LarsStegelitz yes, i knew this answer was familiar to me. In our researches we saw this but could not solve the Problem with that.